# How to generate a two dimensional array from csv data?

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, increment

Assume my csv file will get a two dimensional array, how to put them in `$array[][]`?

```
if (($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $dtary[$d][$c] = $data[$c];
            if ($c == $num) {
                 $d++;
            }
        } 
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($dtary);
```

I am getting only last row of csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that `$d` is ever incremented based on your `for()` loop conditions.  The code inside the loop simply isn't run when `$c==$num`.

This is a method that actually works and offers the benefits of not calling `count()` nor incrementing counters.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5d144ac1f9966277435762942104db3d8742de1))

```
if(($handle=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/file.csv","r"))!==FALSE){
    while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))!==FALSE){
        $inner=[];             // start a fresh inner array
        foreach($data as $d){
            $inner[]=$d;       // build inner array with current row's data
        }
        $dtary[]=$inner;       // push row data as a subarray into result array
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_export($dtary);
```

While I would urge your to implement my code snippet, if you wanted to try to salvage your original code, you could do something like this:

```
if(($handle=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/file.csv","r"))!==FALSE){
    $d=0;
    while(($data=fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))!==FALSE){
        $num=count($data);
        for($c=0; $c<$num; $c++){
            $dtary[$d][$c]=$data[$c];
        }
        $d++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($dtary);
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes sir. Why the code inside for loop isn't incrementing? I don't understand that part.

Comment: You had an "illogical" condition inside the loop.  This part `$c < $num;` of the `for` loop tells the loop when to `break`.  If you had something like `$c <= $num;` then the final iteration would allow `$c==$num` to be true.  That is just an example, you shouldn't change the for condition because it would cause other problems.  Does that make sense to you? or should I try to explain differently?